# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token, did I miss something before that line?

Tags: c

```
#include <video_defines.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <x86/asm.h>

#define HIDDEN 1
#define NOT_HIDDEN 0

typedef struct{
  int row;
  int col;
  int color;
  int cursor;
}console_info;

/* Setting up console info */
console_info *console;
console->row = 0;
console->col = 0;
console->color = (FGDN_WHITE | BKGN_BLACK);
console->cursor = NOT_HIDDEN;
```

Have no ideas about why getting these errors.

```
console.c:19: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
console.c:20: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
console.c:21: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
console.c:22: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
```

These errors should mean I am missing something like semi-colon before line 19. But I can't spot it..

Comment: I changed it the `console_info console = {0, 0, (FGDN_WHITE | BKGN_BLACK), NOT_HIDDEN}` and solved the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have non-declaration statements outside functions. Put the code inside a function, such as `main`:

```
console_info * console;

int main()
{
    console = malloc(sizeof(console_info));  // just an example
    console->row = 0;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Unless he had a specific reason otherwise I would also put the declaration of console inside the main function.

Comment: But I want to set that as global variables. Isn't global variable can be declare outside?

Comment: Your `console` is "the" global variable. But your method cannot work in any way -- it's a *pointer* to data and so you correctly used `->`, but you never allocate the memory to point to.